# Suppress native keyboard events in Firefox (select tag)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, yui

I'm trying to suppress the normal keyboard events on Firefox's interpretation of the `<select multiple="multiple">` box, but the methods I'm used to aren't working. YUI's `stopEvent` doesn't seem to actually suppress the effects of a `keypress` or `keydown` (or both).

```
keyPressHandler = function (e) {
    YUE.stopEvent(e);
};
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(element, 'keypress', keyPressHandler)
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(element, 'keydown', keyPressHandler)
```

Assuming element is a selectbox, the keyboard it still usable to navigate the selectbox in Firefox, however it is not in Chrome. Any ideas on how to properly suppress keyboard events in Firefox?

I generally don't step outside the bounds of YUI but if there is another solution I'm open to it.

Comment: YUE.stopEvent should actually expand to : YAHOO.util.Event.stopEvent

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var keyPressHandler = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  // prevents any default actions of the browser
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevents the event mechanism from bubbling
    return false;        // If there is any condition on the return value, assure it fails
};

element.addEventListener('keydown',keyPressHandler,false);
```

Comment: I don't know how the keydown event works on form elements but as far as I know, this is what you can do with a "raw" event.